# How to insert values recieved from form into a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having following query:

```
INSERT INTO questions (question_parent_id, question_subject_id, question_topic_id, 
question_directions, question_text, question_file, question_description, 
question_difficulty_type, question_has_sub_ques, question_picked_individually, 
question_manual, question_site_id, question_created_staff_id, question_added_date, 
question_appeared_count, question_updated_staff_id, question_updated_date) 
SELECT question_parent_id, question_subject_id, question_topic_id, 
question_directions, question_text, question_file, question_description, 
question_difficulty_type, question_has_sub_ques, question_picked_individually, 
question_manual, question_site_id, question_created_staff_id, question_added_date, 
question_appeared_count, question_updated_staff_id, question_updated_date 
FROM questions 
WHERE question_subject_id='8' 
 AND question_topic_id='545'
```

Now in above query I want to insert a field value for

question_subject_id = $form_data['to_subject_id'];
    and
    question_topic_id = $form_data['from_topic_id'];

I tried below query but it's giving me an error. Can anyone help me please?

```
INSERT INTO questions (question_parent_id, (question_subject_id, '8'), 
(question_topic_id, '547'), question_directions, question_text, question_file, 
question_description, question_difficulty_type, question_has_sub_ques, 
question_picked_individually, question_manual, question_site_id, 
question_created_staff_id, question_added_date, question_appeared_count, 
question_updated_staff_id, question_updated_date) 
SELECT question_parent_id, question_subject_id, question_topic_id, 
question_directions, question_text, question_file, question_description, 
question_difficulty_type, question_has_sub_ques, question_picked_individually, 
question_manual, question_site_id, question_created_staff_id, 
question_added_date, question_appeared_count, question_updated_staff_id, 
question_updated_date 
FROM questions 
WHERE question_subject_id='8' 
 AND question_topic_id='545'
```

Comment: @user1336827:The error is as follows:
MySQL Error: 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(question_subject_id, '8'), (question_topic_id, '547'), question_directions, que' at line 1)
Session halted.

Comment: I'm guessing your second query isn't your attempt.  In addition you don't insert once the record is present you update it.

Comment: I assume that subject_id and question_topic_id are of type integer. Then you don't have to use the single quotes ''! 
`WHERE question_subject_id=8 AND question_topic_id=545`

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO questions (question_parent_id, (question_subject_id, '8'), (question_topic_id, '547'), question_directions, ... )
```

The correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, col2 ...
```

If you want to add variables into your statement, you probably want those at the end

```
$stmt = '... FROM questions 
         WHERE question_subject_id = ' . $form_data['to_subject_id']
         . ' AND question_topic_id = ' . $form_data['from_topic_id'];
```

This method is not recommended as it may be vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [prepared statements.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Comment: Actually I want to change only the two field values from the select query. As per your answer I can add the values at the end only in case of select statement. But I can not understand how to use these two variable values in Insert statement?

Comment: @PHPLover You want to do *what* ? If you want to change the actual *values* from the `SELECT` statement, then you would write something like `$stmt = 'INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) SELECT col1, ' . $val;`

Comment: Are you saying to replace the fields with the variables of which values I want to insert into a database?And keep other part of Select statement as it is.

Comment: I really don't know what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL query should be framed as follows-

```
$sql="INSERT INTO questions (question_parent_id, question_subject_id, question_topic_id, 
question_directions, question_text, question_file, question_description, 
question_difficulty_type, question_has_sub_ques, question_picked_individually, 
question_manual, question_site_id, question_created_staff_id, question_added_date, 
question_appeared_count, question_updated_staff_id, question_updated_date) 
SELECT question_parent_id, question_subject_id, question_topic_id, 
question_directions, question_text, question_file, question_description, 
question_difficulty_type, question_has_sub_ques, question_picked_individually, 
question_manual, question_site_id, question_created_staff_id, question_added_date, 
question_appeared_count, question_updated_staff_id, question_updated_date 
FROM questions 
WHERE question_subject_id='".$form_data['to_subject_id']."' 
AND question_topic_id='".$form_data['from_topic_id']."'";
```

Comment: This is a re-statement of my answer.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO but what if the OP wishes for a poorly formatted version of your answer?